# configured terminal encoding in goland

Tags: goland

OS Windows. After updating goland to version 2020.2 in the terminal (run, debug), Russian characters are displayed like this

[image]

where the encoding is configured?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue. We are tracking it here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/GO-9754